# Databricks cluster permissions to prevent cluster deletion

Tags: databricks

Can a user with "Can manage" permission delete a databricks cluster? If yes, what permissions should be setup to prevent deletion of a all purpose cluster by a user with such permission?
We need to restrict users with "can manage" cluster permissions from deleting the cluster.

Permission settings to prevent cluster deletion

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately when user has "Can Manage" permission it can remove the cluster ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/security/access-control/cluster-acl.html#cluster-level-permissions)).  But it's a general question - why users needs to have "Can Manage" permissions on the clusters that are used by multiple persons?

I would recommend to have cluster configuration defined in Terraform or at least as JSON configuration file so it could be restored quickly via databricks-cli or REST API.